# Probability of getting both task the same week

Tags: probability

Let's say i have a task in my planning that is recurring every two weeks. I have another task that is recurring every two weeks as well. If both of theses tasks starts the same week, i'll have them in my planning at the same time every two weeks.

However, if one task starts on the week 1 and the other the week 2, i'll never have both of them on the same week.

How can i express this mathematically? I mean, what is the formula that could give me the probability (in this case, 1 or 0) of chance of getting both tasks the same week, depending on which week they start?

*In this example, i use two tasks with the same frequency (once every two weeks) but the formula should also work in more complex cases, like if one task happens once every 3 weeks and the other once every 5 weeks*

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite precise, but in many cases making it precise is part of the problem. So let's begin by expressing this mathematically. We have two tasks, $A$ and $B$, and $A$ occurs every $x$ weeks and $B$ occurs every $y$ weeks. Let's express this a little differently: We will say task $A$ occurs on weeks $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots$ and task $B$ occurs on weeks $b_0, b_1, b_2, \dots$. Of course, they occur at regular intervals, so we will maintain that $a_{i+1} = a_i + x$ and $b_{i+1} = b_i + y$. This is another way of saying that once a task has occurred, it occurs again exactly $x$ or $y$ weeks after (depending on whether it is task $A$ or $B$).

The sequences $a$ and $b$ that we have created here are what are known as **arithmetic sequences**. I will talk about some properties here, but you should look them up. You are asking about the properties of the sequence $c$ containing all numbers found in either $a$ or $b$. I will list some of these properties here. You should try and prove that these are true, and hopefully you will gain some intuition by proving this:

1. $c$ is either empty or an arithmetic sequence
2. if $c$ is non-empty, then the period of the sequence is exactly the least common multiple of $x$ and $y$.
3. $c$ is empty precisely if the difference between $a_0$ and $b_0$ is a multiple of the greatest common divisor of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: In deed i know the question was not precise, the main problem i had was to name it correctly. I knew it had a name and was probably trivial, but i couldn't figure out what to search... that was, as you said, a big part of the problem. Your explanation is quite clear, thank you :)